# Two applications on the same server use the same JSESSIONID

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, tomcat6, jsessionid

(**I am using spring-security and tomcat 6**)

I have two applications `A` and `B` which are running on the same server. I have a situation which I am unable to solve.

When I log in the `A` application, `JSESSION` takes a new value, say `v-a`.
(This might be irrelevant, but might be good as well: *As I am using spring security and I have enabled the session-migration, every time I request for the index page, a new value will be assigned to `JSESSIONID`*)

Then I request for `B` application. The request goes with `JESSIONID = v-a`, and the `JSESSIONID` takes a new value, say `v-b`. (most probably because of session-migration the old value is replaced with the new one).

Now when I want to use `A` application, the requests goes with `JESSIONID = v-b`! Which means that these two applications are using the same session? And the nasty thing about it is that I am thrown away from the first application and have to log in again...

*This only happens when they both use the same IP. I have logged in the very same two applications with different IPs with no problem.*

Any help would be appreciated. If you need extra information, just let me know.

Comment: I think that Fiddler trace will help to understand what is the problem. You can attach it to the question :)

Comment: In particular look at the path attributes of your session cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete details:

Application `A` uses *localhost:8080/dtts/dtts/a* 
Application `B` uses *localhost:8080/dtts/dtts/b* 
For every `URL/Path` a cookie with name `JSESSIONID` is set. For both applications we have:
URL: localhost
Path: dtts (and the rest is ignored)

That's why the second cookie replaces the first one. Problem solved.